# why this regex cannot find the result

Tags: python, regex

I have a python code like below: My question is why the matched variable is [' ']? (I used the regex in regexpal.com, it can find the right result |Name=A. Johnson | there)

```
import re
a = 
'{{Infobox U.S. Cabinet |align=left |clear=yes |Name=A. Johnson |President=Andrew Johnson |President start=1865 |President end=1869 |Vice President=None |Vice President start=1865 |Vice President end=1869 |State=[[William H. Seward]] |State start=1865 |State end=1869 |War=[[Edwin M. Stanton]] |War start=1865 |War end=1868 |War 2=[[John Schofield|John M. Schofield]] |War start 2=1868 |War end 2=1869 |Treasury=[[Hugh McCulloch]] |Treasury start=1865 |Treasury end=1869 |Justice=[[James Speed]] |Justice start=1865 |Justice end=1866 |Justice 2=[[Henry Stanberry]] |Justice start 2=1866 |Justice end 2=1868 |Justice 3=[[William M. Evarts]] |Justice start 3=1868 |Justice end 3=1869 |Post=[[William Dennison (Ohio governor)|William Dennison]] |Post start=1865 |Post end=1866 |Post 2=[[Alexander Randall|Alexander W. Randall]] |Post start 2=1866 |Post end 2=1869 |Navy=[[Gideon Welles]] |Navy start=1865 |Navy end=1869 |Interior=[[John P. Usher]] |Interior date=1865 |Interior 2=[[James Harlan (senator)|James Harlan]] |Interior start 2=1865 |Interior end 2=1866 |Interior 3=[[Orville H. Browning]] |Interior start 3=1866 |Interior end 3=1869 }}'
matched = re.findall("\|?\s*name\s*=(.)*?\|",a,re.I)
```

Comment: I see why the result is different from python and regexpal.com.  Python's regex will treat () differently than others. the () of findall in python will return the material in (), not as a whole. So simply change \|?\s*name\s*=(.)*?\| to \|?\s*name\s*=.*?\| can solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want `(.*?)`, not `(.)*?`—the latter (what you have) will only capture a single character, even if it *consumes* more than a single one. A capture group will only be returned once even if the group itself has a repeat; so the latter captures a single character `(.)` despite its repeat.

If you move the repeat into the capture group with `(.*?)`, you'll get more than a single character in the return.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be how it's handling grouping. As a simpler example, look at the difference between the output of the following lines of code:

```
re.findall("c(a)*t", "hi caaat hi")
re.findall("c(a*)t", "hi caaat hi")
```

It looks like the code you want would be more like:

```
re.findall("\|\s*name\s*=([^\|\}]*)", a, re.I)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
matched = re.findall("\|?\s*[nN]ame\s*=([a-zA-Z\.\s]+)\|?",a,re.I)
print matched
```

output:

```
['A. Johnson ']
```